# Доступ к члену несконструированного класса

Tags: c++, классы, конструктор

```
void foo();

struct A {
  int m{};
  A() { foo(); }
} a;

void foo() {
  (void) a.m; // <--
}
```

Допустимо ли таким образом обращаться к члену класса, если конструктор ещё не закончил работу? Какое значение будет у этого члена в этот момент? Можно ли писать в него?

Comment: в целом, пока конструктор не отработал полностью,  объект не сконструирован. Обращаться к членам такого класса - неопределенное поведение. Такой код - плохой.

Comment: @KoVadim `m` же инициализируется ещё до начала тела конструктора `A`

Comment: а это не имеет значение. Не нужно пытаться обмануть компилятор. Хотите, что бы Ваш код работал - передайте указатель на объект в функцию (`foo(this)`). Тогда будет работать.